# Taking unique inputs in an integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a simple program wherein the user enters a few values in an integer array.The code I have written till now is this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){

    int array[10],x,y;

    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
    { 
        scanf("%d",&array[x]);
        //if the entered value is same as any of
        //the previously entered values
        //prompt the user to enter again till
        //he enters a unique value.

        }      }
```

I want the integers in the array to be unique and in case the user enters a previously entered value, he should  be prompted to enter again.
How can I possibly do it?. 
Using a goto statement perhaps? But that is highly discouraged I guess.
Using  a while loop?. But I need to loop through the previously entered values to check for duplicates and I am not able to code this.
Any help appreciated

Comment: "I need to loop through the previously entered values to check for duplicates and I am not able to code this" - why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
    int array[10],x,y;

    x = 0;
    while ( x < 10 ) {
        int duplicated = 0;

        scanf("%d",&array[x]);

        //if the entered value is same as any of
        //the previously entered values
        //prompt the user to enter again till
        //he enters a unique value.
        for ( y = 0; y < x; y++ ) {
            if ( array[x] == array[y] ) {
                printf( "You already entered this! Try again.\n" );
                duplicated = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( ! duplicated )
            x++;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Should probably fix that `void main` while you're at it ?

Comment: @PaulR I'll leave it as is and your comment can be a reminder that it _should_ return an `int`.